# 301 Redirect leads to 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm at my wits end with this one. I've set up URL redirects from my old domain to my new one but instead of going to the URL I've designated, I'm being taken to the new domain but the old folder path (see below). This is what I have in my .htaccess file; I've stripped out all of the other redirects for now except one, because I believe if I can get this one working I can get the rest of them going:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about\-us/$ http://bsmtechnologies.com/about_us/why_bsm/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The URL http://www.bsmwireless.com/about-us/ should redirect to http://bsmtechnologies.com/about_us/why_bsm/, however it is trying to redirect for http://bsmtechnologies.com/about-us/ instead, which is not a page on the new domain.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did it have type into the rewrite rule? `^about\-us/$` -> `^/about\-us/$`

Comment: That did not do the trick, unfortunately.